# Import data to Google sheet from a live website

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to import villages data from state government website (Madhya Pradesh State in India). The website is http://saara.mp.gov.in/saaraweb/PublicReport/frm_PerWiseGirdavariStatus.aspx In this page the report is shown off all the district of Madhya Pradesh State. I want to import all the villages data. My target district is **"37-सिवनी"**. The district name is in first column and its position changes according to the percentage of work done by all the districts. When I click on the **"37-सिवनी"** the javascript shows me all the tahsil(towns) of **"37-सिवनी"** which are 08. My target town is **"06-घंसाैर"** its position also changes according to the work done percentage by all towns. When I click on **"06-घंसाैर"** the list of villages of **"06-घंसाैर"** is now shown with the desired data I want. I want this data to be imported automatically to my googlesheet in specific time. I tried **importhtml** and **importxml** but it did not work for me as the data is not directly available in the url http://saara.mp.gov.in/saaraweb/PublicReport/frm_PerWiseGirdavariStatus.aspx. Do some know how to import data which shows after clicking on some javascript object. It will be very helpful for me. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FfjDh5-z0EIZ5GBOrKElgi3dkRtJX_4BW3imTLUu7ds/edit?usp=sharing In the sheet **"want"** you can see the type of data I want to import and in **"got"** sheet is the data what I got when I try to import using importhtml function.

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheets does not support **scraping** JavaScript content/elements so the best you can have is:

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://saara.mp.gov.in/saaraweb/PublicReport/frm_PerWiseGirdavariStatus.aspx"; 
 "table"; 1)
```

[image: 0]

you can easily test what can be imported simply by disabling JS for a given site like this:

[image: 0]

Comment: How. Disabling javascript will stop the data to show.

Comment: @SushantPeter exactly